# Kubernetes node.js container cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, kubernetes, mongodb-atlas

So I've been struggling with this all afternoon. I can't at all get my NodeJS application running on kubernetes to connect to my MongoDB Atlas database.

In my application I've tried running

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@<project>.gcp.mongodb.net/project_prod?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

but I simply get the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.<project>.gcp.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19)
(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 17)
```

I've tried setting up a ExternalName service too, but using either the URL or the ExternalName results in me not being able to connect to the database.

I've whitelisted my IP on MongoDB Atlas, so I know that isn't the issue.

It also seems to work on my local machine, but not in the kubernetes pod. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you allow all IP addresses to be whitelisted and then try the same?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, which makes sense because it appears to be a DNS error. Mongoose will give an error stating your IP is not whitelisted if you connect from an invalid host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the issue, my pod DNS was not configured to allow external connections, so I set `dnsPolicy: Default` in my YML, because oddly enough `Default` is not actually the default value

Answer (score 1):

I use MongoDB Atlas from Kubernetes but on AWS. Although for testing purposes you can enable all IP addresses and test, here is the approach for a production setup:

- MongoDB Atlas supports Network Peering
- Under Network Access > New Peering Connection
- In the case of AWS, VPC ID, CIDR and Region have to be specified. For GCP it should be the standard procedure used for VPC peering.

Comment: So I've set this all up on google cloud platform, but I can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to connect my application once I'm using this. How do you do it?

Comment: First, can you verify if your app is able to connect to the service from within a local Docker image of your app?

Comment: Great. Can you create a temperory VM in the same VPC as that of your K8s cluster and connect to Atlas? This is to verify peering

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Pods are deployed on nodes in a cluster and not on your service (**so Mongo won't recognise your service endpoints **e.g**; load balancer IP**). Based on this, there are two solutions:

**solution A**

1. Add the endpoint of the Kubernetes cluster to the MongoDB network access IP whitelist.
2. Under the pod spec of your k8s pod (or deployment) manifest, add a **dnsPolicy** field with value set to **Default**. Hence, your Pods (your container basically) will connect to mongo through the name resolution configuration of the master node.

**solution B**

1. Add all node endpoints in your k8s cluster to the MongoDB network access IP whitelist.
2. Under the pod spec of your k8s pod (or deployment) manifest, add a **dnsPolicy** field with the value set to **ClusterFirstWithHostNet**. Since the pods run with your host network, they gain access to services listening on localhost.

[Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)